# Signing Up for Twitter on Tor DEMANDS Phone Verification

Tags: anonymity

I'm trying to sign up for Twitter on Tor, but whenever I do, I'm asked to give out a phone number for verification - which would render Tor useless as they would see my location.

No matter what, there is no link to skip the phone verification.

It loads in IE, and the link has a URL, but using it in Tor redirects you back to the phone verification page!

I have searched everywhere for an answer to this, and nothing works.

This has been a problem for months, and I figured Tor would've found a way around it by now.

Just what are you supposed to do?

Comment: Twitter are able to tell that your traffic is coming from a Tor exit node - all the exit node IP addresses are publicly available. They presumably don't want Tor users creating unverifiable accounts, so are adding the phone verification requisite. You could attempt to use a VPN in conjunction with Tor - or a VPN by itself - and see if you have any further luck. I suspect trying to contact Twitter would fall on deaf ears...

Comment: It's ridiculous. It really is. So why does Twitter work on Android through Orbot? Would I not be able to to use an android emulator and then run Orbot? And how do I know the VPN isn't a honeypot?

Comment: you can use get a burner number app on your phone which will givea fake number but i havent been able to get it cause it requires java

Comment: I just tried this with email verification instead of mobile number with Tor and it didn't work. It said I was breaking Twitter rules...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as of 2022, the same issue applies to Twitter's onion service (which one would hope would be more privacy-friendly).  Registering via the onion appears to work with only an email address (it requires a CAPTCHA, but the CAPTCHA is not difficult), but the account gets locked a few minutes after registration, at which point Twitter demands a phone number.

(Would have posted this as a comment since that's the right place for it, but it seems Stack Exchange won't let me post it there.)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you are willing to spend more money, you can buy a burner phone with it's own sim card and after registration, throw it away.

However if currently (or in the future for the other people reading answer) you are from places where buying sim cards requires registration with your identity, government agencies can still track you down. That will also depend on your [threat model](https://ssd.eff.org/en/module/introduction-threat-modeling) if it includes these adversarial agencies or not.